# TYPO3 6.2 – Add JS file in action with enabled cache

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I've been trying to include a JS file with addJsFooterFile() like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->getPageRenderer()->addJsFooterFile(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::siteRelPath('my_extension') . 'Resources/Public/JavaScripts/MyAction.js');
```

When I disable caching in ext_localconf.php, the js file is included at the last position of all js files in the footer and everything works fine. But – if I enable caching for that action, it is included at the very first position of all js files and i can't access any js libraries... Do you know how to solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Within the controller action you can append a script tag to the header tag:

```
$this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<script type="text/javascript" src="' . ExtensionManagementUtility::siteRelPath($this->request->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/Public/Scripts/<YourJSFile>.js" /></script>');
```